# Make variable method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a XP Leveling system in unity. At the moment my code works (this first part is inside the onclick method):

```
     currentExp = Xp.LevelToXP(combat + 1);

     if (combatExp + 5 < currentExp)
     {
         combatExp += 5;
         if (previousExp == 0)
         {
             float fill = (float)(currentExp) / 100;
             XpBar.fillAmount += (5 / fill) / 100;
         }
         else
         {
             float fill = (float)(currentExp - previousExp) / 100;
             XpBar.fillAmount += (5 / fill) / 100;
         }
     }
     else if (combatExp + 5 == currentExp)
     {
         combatExp += 5;
         combat++;
         previousExp = currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount = 0;
     }
     else if (combatExp + 5 > currentExp)
     {
         combatExp += 5;
         combat++;
         previousExp = currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount = 0;
         float remainingExp = (float)combatExp - currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount += (remainingExp / currentExp) / 100f;
     }
     txtCombatLvl.text = "Combat Level: " + combat;
```

this is what happens when you press the button.

but when i try to put all of this in a method instead of the onclick method

```
 void AddExp (int skill, int skillExp, int expAmount)
 {
     currentExp = Xp.LevelToXP(skill + 1);

     if (skillExp + expAmount < currentExp)
     {
         skillExp += expAmount;
         if (previousExp == 0)
         {
             float fill = (float)(currentExp) / 100;
             XpBar.fillAmount += (expAmount / fill) / 100;
         }
         else
         {
             float fill = (float)(currentExp - previousExp) / 100;
             XpBar.fillAmount += (expAmount / fill) / 100;
         }
     }
     else if (skillExp + expAmount == currentExp)
     {
         skillExp += expAmount;
         skill++;
         previousExp = currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount = 0;
     }
     else if (skillExp + expAmount > currentExp)
     {
         skillExp += expAmount;
         skill++;
         previousExp = currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount = 0;
         float remainingExp = (float)skillExp - currentExp;
         XpBar.fillAmount += (remainingExp / currentExp) / 100f;
     }
 }
```

And I try to access it by calling it like this:

AddExp(combat, combatExp, 5);

none of my combat xp and level don't save. Can someone point me in the right direction since none of what i tried worked.

Comment: Can you post complete code samples?  It is difficult to see where things might be going wrong after your modifications with only visibility into the function itself.  I don't see any save logic in there, so it follows that that might be done outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of a C# method are passed by value and not by references, so changes to them inside a function are local to the function.  If you want the values updated then you prefix them with the `ref` keyword.

```
void AddExp (ref int skill, ref int skillExp, int expAmount)
```

**Alternate Solution**
Alternatively, you could simplify your design with an encapsulation of your concept of a Skill with a class.  Here's a possibility,  I couldn't quite follow your math and am not familiar with your other classes, so you can adjust this as necessary.

```
   public class Skill
   {
      private string _name;
      private int _currentValue;
      private int _currentLevel = 1;

      public Skill(string name) {
      }

      public string Name { get { return _name; } }

      public int CurrentXp { get { return _currentValue; } }
      public int CurrentLevel { get { return _currentLevel; } } 
      public int XpRequiredForNextLevel { get { return Xp.LevelToXP(_currentLevel + 1); } }
      public int XpRequiredForCurrentLevel { get { return Xp.LevelToXP(_currentLevel); } }

      private float CalculateFillPercentage(int xp)
      {
         var xpInLevel = XpRequiredForNextLevel - XpRequiredForCurrentLevel;
         return (float)(xp - XpRequiredForCurrentLevel) / (float)xpInLevel;
      }

      public void AddXp(int expAmount) 
      {
         _currentValue += expAmount;
         int XpInCurrentLevel = XpRequiredForNextLevel - XpRequiredForCurrentLevel;
         if (_currentValue > XpRequiredForNextLevel) {
         } else {
            _currentLevel++;
         }
         XpBar.fillAmount = CalculateFillPercentage (_currentValue);        
      }
   }
```

You could use this by holding instances of each skill, for example:

```
Skill combat = new Skill("combat");
```

And then later

```
combat.AddXp(50);
```

Each skill would be self contained.  I'm not sure about the XpBar or how that is controlled between different types of skills, but you could further encapsulate by calculating internally, so the skill provides everything your UI needs to keep up to date.

Comment: *"The parameters of a C# method are passed by value"* Doesn't this only apply to *value types*, not *reference types*?

Comment: Not really, with a reference you are still passing by value, but you are already passing a reference so you can modify the contents of the reference type, but not the reference itself. so with `void Foo(MyClass...)` you could update the properties of the MyClass instance, but not which MyClass instance the outer function is pointing to.

Comment: While this will certainly work, it does feel like a not so neat solution. I would suggest you add a paragraph about passing the actual object containing those variables. Or yes, moving the code to the actual class.